# Is this external monitor going to be compatible with my Macbook Air M1?

Tags: display, resolution, apple-silicon

I am thinking about buying a second-hand monitor. This is the model:

Monitor LG Ultrawide 29WL500-29", 21:9 IPS, HDMI, HDR10, Screen Split 2.0

The computer on the Brazilian version of [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com.br/gp/product/B099NX3P3F/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Specifications:

| Characteristic type | Data |
| --- | --- |
| Size | 29'' |
| Maximum resolution | 2560 x 1080 |
| Brand | LG |
| Special characteristics | Height Adjustment, Anti Glare Screen, Ultrawide Screen, Flicker-Free |
| Refresh rate | 75HZ |

Also, I have a MacBook Air M1:

[image]

Finally, I have a DELL adapter for HDMI stuff.

Is this compatible? Am I going to have problems?

Comment: Why should it not be, assuming you have an USB-C - HDMI adapter?

Comment: I do not know. I always assume there could be problems. I have suffered a lot with monitors in the past, resolution incompatibility... among other problems

Comment: Bleah, it's HDMI-only, and it's LG.  That aspect ration is just weird.  If you were getting it for free, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those dimensions are correct (they seem a bit weird), that's a pixel density of 96ppi, which is very low.

Realistically, low-PPI displays look very poor on macOS. I'd suggest looking for a 27-inch display with 2560 x 1440 pixels (109ppi) at minimum, if not 4K (163ppi). Or even a 24-inch display at 2560 x 1440 (122ppi).

Comment: Thanks. I have inserted the link sent by the seller with the specifications on the Amazon website (Brazilian version).